# Python Relative imports.. again

Tags: python, python-3.8

I have - ofc - got stuck on the relative imports, again.. I dont know why after a while I always come back to this problem, which just makes me crazy for obvious reasons, however i read the docs, posts here, and just want to put it out there. Let's assume this project:

```
-- myproject/
      - main.py {...}
      --first_package/
          -__init__.py
          -a.py   {from second_package import c}
          -b.py   {from second_package.c import foo}
      --second_package/
          -__init__.py
          -c.py   {def foo(): pass}
```

After an hour i just decided to put it here for my future self as well as for you.

Imports from **a.py** and **b.py** will not work when you run the scripts **directly** like this `python3 first_package/[a|b].py`, it will throw *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'second_package'*

This will work only if **A and B are imported themselves.**

So in *main.py*: `import first_package.a` and then the imports inside those modules will work. I dont know but lot of posts and tutorials miss this out. Once in a while i just forget that i have to go through main.py and once a year i lose an hour of my life.

Also I do not want to go through docs for this so if anyone has technical explanation for this, please feel free to explain in detail. Have fun guys, Q.

Answer (score 1):

The module search path is not relative to the working directory but to the main module you are running.

Thus, with `python3 first_package/a.py`, it is the `a.py` script that is considered the main module.
When interpreting `from second_package import c`, Python will therefore search for a potential `c.py` module located in `first_package/second_package` instead of `myproject/second_package`.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem the easiest way is simply to set the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` so that it point to the absolute path to `my_project` folder.

You can do this in bash when located in `my_project`.

```
export PYTHONPATH=`pwd -P`
```

I simply create a `source_me.sh` file at the root of all my projects.
Can be done using a `.bat` file as well.